# Aritmetic operation on Cron pattern

Tags: cron

I have a use case I need to schedule 2 tasks
1. At 'x' time which is defined by cron pattern
2. At 'x minus 2 hours' for which I need to calculate cron pattern based on first cron pattern

For eg 
If the first task is scheduled at 1 o'clock everyday 
0 01 * * *
So we to find out first task time minus two hours,  that would be 0 23 * * *

Please someone suggest on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Are you trying to implement timezones in such way?

Comment: No,  I have a job running every day once. The time is taken as input from user. This job has some prerequisite which needs to be run sometime before ( for now 2 hours before ) . So have to find a cron pattern based on first job.

Comment: Then it's not possible. What you could potentially do is to calculate next ocurrence and subtract two hours from such calculated occurence.